# Detect if connected battery is rechargeable

Tags: battery-charging, charger, battery-operated, detection

The device I am building can be powered by USB or 3xAAA batteries. While connected to the USB, the device will charge the batteries. But before charging the batteries, the device needs to make sure the batteries are rechargeable.

I've made a circuit using BQ2002 to charge the batteries. If the batteries are not rechargeable, this circuit should not attempt to charge the battery (set charge control on BQ2002 to low).

How can I make sure my circuit doesn't try to charge every connected battery?
Is there a IC that has this functionality?

Comment: Usually the system for connecting the batteries would allow you to differentiate between batteries, e.g. special holder when using primary cells that has a different pin-out than the rechargeable battery pack.

Comment: Or, have smart/authenticated battery packs: rechargeable batteries with an I2C or 1-wire memory. Assume non-rechargeable otherwise.

Comment: In my box of spare batteries, the alkaline AAAs have a small +ve pip, the NimHs have a large +ve pip. You may want to check if that is always the case, whether it is part of the battery specifications. If so, they may be available battery holders with a guard around the +ve contact that can detect which sort of cell is in. If not, detecting the chemistry from the terminals alone may be rather difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Maxim (was Dallas Semi) [DS2711](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/battery-management/DS2711.html) and [DS2712](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/battery-management/DS2712.html) NiMh chargers include functionality to detect primary (i.e. non-rechargeable) cells. They do this by measuring the internal impedance of the cells, and using that to differentiate between NiMh (lower impedance) and primary cells (higher impedance), as explained in this [Maxim Application Note 3388](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3388).

The abstract from that AppNote says:

> The DS2711 and DS2712 Loose Cell NiMH Chargers (designed for one or
>   two AA or AAA NiMH "loose" cells) detect an alkaline primary cell and
>   avoid charging it. This application note characterizes a wide variety
>   of used and new cells from a variety of manufacturers and shows how
>   the charger ICs can distinguish between NiMH rechargeable cells and
>   alkaline primary cells.

Unfortunately for your application, as you can see in that abstract, those Maxim devices are designed for recharging 1 or 2 cells - not your 3-cell design. Options include modifying your design to use only 1 or 2 cells and, if your design needs it, adding a boost converter to match the higher output voltage of 3 cells (assuming the existing 3-cell design has them connected in series) or trying to incorporate the same impedance measurement technique as they use, into your own design (but perhaps check for any patents that might apply, if you do that).

Comment: Thank you. I actually found the DS2714 thanks to you. "The DS2714 is ideal for standalone charging of 1 to 4
AA or AAA NiMH “loose” cells. "

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I didn't mention the [DS2714](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/battery-management/DS2714.html) because according to the Maxim website, it is no longer available and only seems to support a parallel cell configuration (I had assumed yours were in series). If you have found genuine stock of the DS2714 somewhere, and it suits your design, then great!

Comment: I found a supplier that sells these and I will manage to select between parallel/series configuration.

Comment: OK, good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Many proprietary methods have been used over time but terminal shape, voltage or charge characteristics are not enough to go by as there is no standard.

Having any kind of smarts in your rechargeable packs would be enough to identify them.

It could be as simple as a over temperature thermistor or current select resistor that would provide added valuable functionality.